# How to run an .Net core Avalonia application in Linux for multiple users

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, debian, avalonia

We have build an .Net Core Avalonia app with the below profile settings

**Target Frame Work**: net7.0

**Deployment Mode** : self-contained

**Target Runtime**: linux-x64

**File Publish Options** : Produce Single File

Now we are trying to programmatically run the app for multiple users in Linux (Version: Ubuntu 20.04, GUI : Debian)

So we copied the files into the Linux Machine by RDP into it `(Path : /opt/AvaloniaApp)`
We provided the required file permissions to all the files in AvaloniaApp folder using the chmod command

```
sudo chmod -R u+rwx AvaloniaApp
```

But it provided the access to root user only. So we provided the access to specific users using chown command

```
sudo chown -R :user1 AvaloniaApp
sudo chown -R :user2 AvaloniaApp
```

user2 is able to run the Application from AvaloniaApp folder using

```
./myappfile
```

But user1 is not able to run the Application due to permission issue
`bash: ./myappfile: Permission denied`, but I already have the access for user1 also.

```
`-rwx------ 1 user2 user1    23516 Nov 28 12:30 myappfile.pdb
-rwx------ 1 user2 user1 99222415 Nov 28 12:30 myappfile
-rwx------ 1 user2 user1    24940 Nov 28 12:30 myappfile.pdb
-rwx------ 1 user2 user1  1607016 Nov 28 12:30 myappfile.so
-rwx------ 1 user2 user1  9478432 Nov 28 12:30 libSkiaSharp.so`
```

So how can multiple users run the application. Anybody have any ideas what might be wrong and how to fix it, we are new to Linux

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you want to create a group, assign users to the new group and then set permissions upon the group object, instead of by individual user.

Please see this example: https://superuser.com/questions/914666/how-to-create-a-group-add-user-to-group-and-give-that-group-full-access-to-dir

However, I would suggest chmod 770, instead of 777.

770 means owner and group have full permissions, while 777 permissions grants read, write, and execute permission to everyone.

As you mentioned you are new to Linux, you might want to try Ubuntu as it is more user friendly than Debian, which is best suited for intermediate to advanced Linux users.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35545527)